# Flutter ScrollController AssertionError: '_positions.isNotEmpty': ScrollController not attached to any scroll views when closing route

Tags: flutter, routes, scroll, navigator, observers

I'm encountering an error in my Flutter application related to a ScrollController. I have a QuestionDetailsScreen where I'm using a ScrollController to monitor the scroll position. I want to trigger a function in my controller `fireWhenCloseQuestionDetails()` when the QuestionDetailsScreen route is closed. To do this, I've implemented a custom NavigatorObserver. However, I'm getting an error:

'_positions.isNotEmpty': ScrollController not attached to any scroll views

**Here's my QuestionBankController:**

```
  class QuestionBankController extends GetxController {
  ScrollController questionDetailsScrollCtrl = ScrollController();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    questionDetailsScrollCtrl = ScrollController();
    questionDetailsScrollCtrl.addListener(_onScroll);
    super.onInit();
  }

  void _onScroll() {
    // This function will be called every time the scroll position changes
    print("Scroll position: ${questionDetailsScrollCtrl.position.pixels}");
  }

  void fireWhenCloseQuestionDetails() {
    print("Fire");
    print(questionDetailsScrollCtrl.position.pixels);
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    print("On close");
    questionDetailsScrollCtrl.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

I'm using a custom `NavigatorObserver` to trigger `fireWhenCloseQuestionDetails()` when the `QuestionDetailsScreen` route is closed:

```
class MyNavigatorObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    if (route.settings.name == "/questiondetailsscreen") {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        QuestionBankController().fireWhenCloseQuestionDetails();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like the issue might be related to creating a new instance of `QuestionBankController` when calling `fireWhenCloseQuestionDetails()`. How can I ensure I'm using the correct instance of `QuestionBankController` associated with my `QuestionDetailsScreen` specifically when closing the route?

**Additional Information:**

- The scroll listening functionality is working correctly while
  scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

How about calling `fireWhenCloseQuestionDetails()` in `QuestionBankController`'s `onClose`?

```dart
@override
void onClose() {
  print("On close");
  fireWhenCloseQuestionDetails();
  questionDetailsScrollCtrl.dispose();
  super.onClose();
}
```

Probably if your `QuestionBankController` is bound to `QuestionDetailsScreen`.

Comment: actually, I use this controller for two pages. that's mean when I get back from QuestionDetailsScreen() to QuestionListScreen() then my controller exist

Comment: I tried also this, but not working

Comment: Then change QuestionDetailsScreen to StatefulWidget, and override onDispose to call fireWhenCloseQuestionDetails.

Comment: still not working